# Internet Explorer download popup automation

Tags: python, internet-explorer, robotframework, autoit

I am trying to automate Internet Explorer's download popup using Robot Framework. My AutoIt script:

```
Sleep(9000);
Local $hIE = WinGetHandle("[Class:IEFrame]");
Local $hCtrl = ControlGetHandle($hIE, "", "[ClassNN:DirectUIHWND1]");
If WinExists($hIE, "") Then
    WinActivate($hIE, "");
    ControlSend($hIE, "", $hCtrl, "{F6}");
    Sleep(1500);
    ControlSend($hIE, "", $hCtrl, "{TAB}");
    Sleep(1500);
    ControlSend($hIE, "", $hCtrl, "{ENTER}");
EndIf
```

This fails. How to handle such cases in Robot framework? Control won't come to next line after click action (Log statement shows its not executing; control is waiting infinitely).

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    css:img#ctl00_ExcelImg
wait until keyword succeeds     30 sec       5 sec     Click Element  css:img#ctl00_ExcelImg
Log  this is log   console=true
```

How to make Internet Explorer download files to a given location by code?

Comment: You have two wait statements in your code and one of them is looping infinitely. You just need to figure out which one and fix that one.

Comment: not really. first line waits till 5sec 2nd one for 30sec with few iterations. jus to make sure my statement i removed wait conditions and ran once again. its same situation. control is waiting infinite post click element.

Comment: Might be its something to do with Popup. Control has to shift/focus on it.

Comment: If you can automatically download the files in IE, maybe you can do something like this: https://gist.github.com/Tset-Noitamotua/ab94b2e1b7ce3642f21429a3f4d89bb7#file-chrome_profile-robot and open the browser using your profile, that contains your settings for the download. Open Browser uses the standard browser settings. I did something similar for Firefox, but i am not sure if it will work for IE